# None of [Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns] error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a main dataframe and want to create a sub-dataframe with specific columns:

```
df_main=
[a,b,c,d]
[1,3,6,0]
```

When I want to pick specific columns and create a new one, it throws me this ugly error:

```
    df_new=
    df.loc[:, ['a','c']]
    df_new.head()

    Out:None of [Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: what's `df`? You define `df_main`...

Comment: what is `print(df.columns)`

Comment: You have to maintain minimal, reproducible and readable code, So please show us the properly formatted DataFrame Structure  with expected output to get an answer.

Comment: Check for whitespace in your column headers.  to fix use `strip`.   `df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right understand:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1], 'b':[3], 'c':[6], 'd':[0]})
df_new = df.loc[:, ['a','c']]
```

df_new:

```
    a   c
0   1   6
```